# Pop up extensão chrome cortando texto

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-extensão

Salve!
Estou fazendo um pop up para minha extensão do chrome mas estou encontrando um problema.
Quando clico no dropdown, o texto fica cortado:

[image: Dropdown cortado]

Acredito que seja porque ele vai para a **direita** mas o chrome não permite a expansão para a direita, já que está chegando no final da tela.
,
Fiz diversas pesquisas sobre como mandar o submenu pra esquerda, tentei usar `float-right` e outras coisas mas sem resultado

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <title>Opções</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap js -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--css e js locais-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="options.css">
  <script src="options.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--container para automatizar o resize-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <!--Drop Down de seleção-->
          <div class="dropdown pull-left">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton"
              data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Ação
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
              <button id="btnLixeiraAnalytics" class="dropdown-item"
                onclick="salvarConfiguração('LixeiraAnalytics')">Limpar Lixeira Analytics</button>
              <button id="btnArtigoDesk" class="dropdown-item" onclick="salvarConfiguração('AtualizarArtigo')">Atualizar
                Artigo</button>
              <button id="btnDesativar" class="dropdown-item"
                onclick="salvarConfiguração('LixeiraAnalytics')">Desativado</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Em suma, a pergunta é: **O que eu faço para que o menu do dropdown não fique cortado?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de muita pesquisa entendi o problema.
O `bootstrap` tenta, de maneira inteligente, identificar pra onde ele pode se expandir. Porém a extensão do chrome aumenta ou diminui de tamanho dinamicamente após o bootstrap ser executado, então o texto fica cortado.
Para contornar isso defini o tamanho do botão que ativa o drop down para ocupar um espaço maior e assim o tamanho que muda dinamicamente ser só a altura.

```html
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Drop Down de seleção-->
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-block" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Ação
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <button id="btnLixeiraAnalytics" class="dropdown-item btn-sm">Limpar Lixeira Analytics</button>
    <button id="btnArtigoDesk" class="dropdown-item btn-sm">Atualizar Artigo</button>
    <button id="btnDesativado" class="dropdown-item btn-sm">Desativado</button>
  </div>
</div>
```